# XSL Transformation from xsd

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am new to xsl transformations and i have a problem with looping child elements. I am trying to get tree of elements values from IN.A.Number1.  My xsd looks like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0">
<xs:element name="Document">
<xs:complexType>
 <xs:all>
<xs:element name="IN">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:all>
<xs:element name="A" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:all>
<xs:element name="Number1" type="Integer" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Number2" type="Integer" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="Number3" type="Integer" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="B" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:all>
<xs:element name="Date1" type="Date" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="String1" type="String" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="Arraydate" minOccurs="0">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="data_type" type="xs:string" fixed="date"/>
<xs:element ref="date_format"/>
<xs:element name="element" type="String Array" maxOccurs="10" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:all>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The output should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mapping name="IN_A_Number1" original name= "B.Date1"/>
.
.
<mapping name="IN_B_Date1 original name= "B.Date1"" />
<mapping name="IN_B_Date1 original name= "B.Date1""/>
.
.
.
</mappings>
```

So far i got elements on the first level but do not know how to write child elements of elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
   exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
   version="1.0">

   <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:for-each select="*">
<mappings>
<xsl:variable name="pom" select="."></xsl:variable>
<xsl:element name="mapping">
<xsl:attribute name="name">
<xsl:value-of select="$pom" />
</xsl:attribute>
<xsl:apply-templates
select="//xs:element[@name = 'IN']/ xs:complexType/xs:all/xs:element"/>
</xsl:element>
</mappings>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="xs:element">

 <mappings>
 <xsl:element name="mapping">
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:call-template name = "xmlToJava">
    <xsl:with-param name="xmlName" select = "concat(./@name,'.',//xs:element[@name = 'IN']/ xs:complexType/xs:all/xs:element[@name='.'])"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:attribute>

</xsl:element>
</mappings>

 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="xmlToJava">
<xsl:param name="xmlName" />
<xsl:value-of select="translate($xmlName, '.','_')" />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Thank you for any help :)

Comment: Are you limited to XSLT 1? Can you post a minimal but complete samples that allow us to reproduce the problem? The code you have shown seems to create elements named `functions` with `xsl:element name="functions"` but I don't see any in the output you say you get nor in the one you say you want.

Comment: Your question needs more details or clarity. Do you want to output only the first child element of `xs:all` or all of them? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Not sure whether it's relevant, but your XSD file is not a valid schema. An xs:element can't directly contain another xs:element.

Comment: @zx485 , i want to output all of them, i.e. take <first child element>.<second child element>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this XSLT-1.0 template to create a list of all `xs:element` leaf nodes:

```
<xsl:template match="/xs:schema" >
    <xsl:element name="mappings">
        <xsl:for-each select=".//xs:element[not(descendant::xs:element)]">
                <mapping>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name">
                        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::xs:element">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                            <xsl:if test="descendant::xs:element">
                                <xsl:text>_</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="originalName">
                        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor-or-self::xs:element[3 > position()]">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
                            <xsl:if test="descendant::xs:element">
                                <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
                            </xsl:if>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </xsl:attribute>                        
                </mapping>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Its output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<mappings xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <mapping name="Document_IN_A_Number1" originalName="A.Number1"/>
  <mapping name="Document_IN_A_Number2" originalName="A.Number2"/>
  <mapping name="Document_IN_A_Number3" originalName="A.Number3"/>
  <mapping name="Document_IN_B_Date1" originalName="B.Date1"/>
  <mapping name="Document_IN_B_String1" originalName="B.String1"/>
  <mapping name="Document_IN_Arraydate_data_type" originalName="Arraydate.data_type"/>
  <mapping name="Document_IN_Arraydate_" originalName="Arraydate."/>
  <mapping name="Document_IN_Arraydate_element" originalName="Arraydate.element"/>
</mappings>
```